# How to use AQTime's memory allocation profiler in a program that uses a large amount of memory?

Tags: delphi, aqtime

I'm finding AQTime hard to use because it interferes with the original program too much. If I have a program that uses, for example, 300MB of ram I can use AQTime's allocation profiler without a problem, and find out where most of the memory is being used. However I notice that running under AQTime, the original program uses more like 1GB while it's being profiled.

Right now I'm trying to reduce memory usage in a program which is using 1.4GB of memory. If I run it under AQTime, then the original program uses all of the 2GB address space and crashes. I can of course invent a smaller set of test data and estimate how the memory usage will scale with the full data set - but the reason I'm using a profiler in the first place is to try to avoid this sort of guesswork.

I already have AQTime set to 'Collect stack information - None' and all the check boxes to do with checking memory integrity are switched off, and I've tried restricting the area being profiled to just a few classes but this doesn't seem to improve anything. Is there a way to use AQTime that produces a smaller overhead? Or failing that, what other approaches are there to get a good idea of the memory being used?

The app is written in Delphi 2010 and I'm using AQTime 6.

NB: On top of the increased memory usage, running under AQTime slows the app down an awful lot, making the whole exercise not just impossible but impractical too :-P

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the allocation profiler will track memory block allocation regardless of profiling areas. Profiling areas are used to track classes instantiation. Of course memory-profiling an application that allocates a large amount of memory is a issue, you may try to use the LARGE_ADRESS_AWARE flag, and the /3GB boot switch, or use a 64 bit system (as long as you have at least 4GB of memory, or more). Also you can take snapshot of the application state before it crashes, to see where the memory is allocated. Profiling takes time, anyway, you may have to let it run for a while.